# Matching 2 rows and copying another row to another row

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel file that has about 1500 data on and about 20 columns. I have 2 sheets:

**Sheet1**

```
Customer Basic ID     Customer ID#     Name     Nationality    Address  ...
02654                 12056978          aa        somewhere
```

**Sheet2**

```
Customer Basic ID     Customer ID#
```

What I need to do is match Customer ID# in sheet1 with sheet2 and get Customer Basic ID into sheet1 in the corresponding column.

I have tried:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(C:C,AH:AH,0)*AG:AG
```

But it did not work.

I tried also addins but I cannot get it working, and when I think of searching for the matching ID and copying it manually I feel like it is very bad solution and time consuming.

Comment: assuming `Customer Basic ID` is column A and `Customer ID#` is Column B in both sheets then in A2 in sheet 2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0))` should do the trick

Comment: @DirkReichel what am I missing here? This just looks like a vlookup?

Comment: vlookup will always search in the first column of the range, but you need to search the second column and output the first one... this cannot be done with vlookup... but basically you are right, it is the same.

Comment: @DirkReichel I shouldn't comment while tired... :)

Comment: In your example Customer Basic ID is already in sheet1. Did I misunderstand the example or question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `Customer Basic ID` from sheet2 based on the `Customer ID#` value from sheet1

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

As you already wrote in your question, `MATCH` tries tries to find B2 (assuming we are in row 2) in Column B in the 2nd sheet. With `INDIRECT` we get the value next to it by stitching the cell address together.